# Php and character for str_replace

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

actually i have problem for use str_replace , i put my example :

```
<?php
$chars_1=array('\',"/","&","¬","~","-","_");
$chars_2=array("","","","","","","");

$result=str_replace($chars_1,$chars_2,$text);

?>
```

The problem it´s when in the array put the character \ , for the rest i haven´t problem but if i put or use \ for change by other character i have problem , how i can replace \ and use in array for replace for nothing in this case , if use this replace with \ the mini script give me error if no use in replace \ all ok

Thank´s !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the slash, by using a double slash:

```
$chars_1 = array('\\',"/","&","¬","~","-","_");
```